# Airflow scheduler keeps terminating

Tags: airflow

After running the airflow scheduler command, I am getting this message:

> The scheduler does not appear to be running. Last heartbeat was received 1 minute ago
> 2023-04-28T21:40:01.842078+00:00
> The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.

In my terminal, I am getting this error:

> {scheduler_job.py:909} INFO - Exiting scheduler loop as requested number of runs (10 - got to 10) has been reached

I've uninstalled and reinstalled airflow a couple of times. I thought it was my dag issue at first, but I have deleted it and I just can't seem to keep the scheduler running. I am currently using the SequentialExecutor and SQLite, not sure if that is the problem but I cannot figure out how to configure any other backend.

Comment: what is your airflow version? local or docker ?